# Procedural generated Z-index using classes

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, z-index

I am trying to create a system for posts that will allow me to produce new posts but as it will be overlapping one to another I am looking for a way to create a different Z-index automatically when creating a new div of that class.

Can it be done with Jquery?

Thanks in advance

here is a JsFiddle for a visual representation of what I have and what Im looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8mkE/8/

```
    z-index:10000
```

Comment: It probably can, if jQuery can find existing properties and apply `++i` to them (or something) and apply the new one to a new item as a property, I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to rely on JS to assign incremental z-index. Instead, we can just increase the z-index of the element you have hovered, so it overlaps the rest.

[<kbd>See fiddle here</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/Q8mkE/14/)

My trick is to rely on jQuery to duplicate the content of each `.article` element, which is hidden by default and only shown when hovered over:

```
$(function() {
    $('.article').each(function() {
        // Create duplicate
        var $dup = $('<div />', {
            'class': 'duplicate'
        }).html($(this).html());

        // Append duplicate
        $dup.appendTo($(this));
    });
});
```

And here is the updated CSS:

```
.article{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: blue;  
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    /* We set their positions to relative so that z-index works */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
    .article:hover {
        /* Increase z-index when hovered on, ensures overflowing content overlaps neighbouring/adjacent divs */
        z-index: 2;
    }

.article > .duplicate {
    background-color: red;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
    .article:hover > .duplicate {
        display: block;
        height: 400px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

I am not sure you need jQuery for this as you said. You can just play with css float and height properties. You can add transition property if you want more beautiful ui ([click me](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8mkE/12/)).

**OLD**

It is not good idea to use `z-index` at all. Are you sure you need it?

Yes, you can manage element css via jQuery.

Look [jQuery .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Example:

```
var counter = 0;
//work with counter
$("#someId").css("z-index", counter);
```

Comment: Id prefer it, I am trying to produce a divs that will expand on :hover but dont want the whole page to disassemble when that happens. I dont know any other other way than z-index to make divs not collide. Thanks for the jquery reference +1

Comment: @Fyxerz You could give them absolute positions and have them move partially off the side of the screen.

Comment: @Luxelin Giving absolute positioning to the elements wont make it work as they will just stack one on top of each other.